# I have problem when showing post in loop using WP_Query in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

i have a problem when trying to show a current 4 post using WP_Query.
But, the older post (The very first post) also shown in the first loop.

This is my code:

```
<?php
    $args = array(
        'post_type'      => 'post',
        'posts_per_page' => '3'
    );
    $query = new WP_Query( $args ); //show 4 post
    if ( $query->have_posts() ){
        /* Start the Loop */
        while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
            $query->the_post();?>
            <div class="col-md-3 d-flex align-items-stretch">
                <div class="card ">
                    <?php if (has_post_thumbnail()) { 
                        $featured_img_url = get_the_post_thumbnail_url(get_the_ID(),'full'); 
                        ?>
                        

                        <img class="miniimg" src="<?php echo $featured_img_url;  ?>" width="auto" height="200px">
                    <?php } ?>
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h4><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                            <?php the_title(); 
                            $post_date = get_the_date( 'j F Y' );
                            ?>
                        </a></h4>
                        <p class="card-text"><?php the_excerpt();?></p>
                        <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                            <div class="btn-group">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">Read More</button>
                            </div>
                            <small class="text-muted"><?= $post_date; ?></small>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <?php 
            $counter++; }
        }
        ?>
```

This is the result => [image: Result image]

How to fix this problem? is there any problem with my code?
Thankyou.

Comment: How does the `$args` array look like for real? The definition you have attached has a limit of 3, so it is not exactly the version you generated the screenshot with...

Comment: @ZoliSzabó sorry, i have changed it. I mean i want to show 4 last post with that query.  'posts_per_page' => '3' it will show 4 post. but my problem is, the very first post is also shown in the first loop. you can see on the attached image.

Comment: @torsinta12 Glad I could help, don't forget to "accept the answer" too, regards.

Comment: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/958/excluding-sticky-posts-from-the-loop-and-from-wp-query-in-wordpress

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If specifying `'posts_per_page' => 3` gives back 4 posts, it is almost 100% sure that the first post is a sticky post. Use the option `ignore_sticky_posts` to ignore them.

```php
    $args = array(
        'post_type'      => 'post',
        'posts_per_page' => 4,
        'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1,
    );
    ...
```

Answer (score 2):

> A Sticky Post is the post will be placed at the top of the front page of posts. This feature is only available for the built-in post type post and not for custom post types.

- *Source @ https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/functionality/sticky-posts/*

I'm pretty sure you applied is sticky to your post from 2012.

To verify you can just add the following to your loop inside the while statement:

```
<?php //...
while( have_posts() ): the_post();
  if( is_sticky() ):
    echo 1;
    else: echo 0;
  endif;
endwhile;
//... ?>
```

Or go to you post in the admin console, and verify that you didn't check the "is sticky" checkbox on the right side in the publish panel.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'movies');
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
?><div class="movie-content" >
    <?php 
        echo '<a href="' . get_permalink( $post->ID ) . '" title="' . esc_attr( $post->post_title ) . '">' ?>
        <h2><?php echo the_title(); ?></h2>
        <div><?php the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail'); ?></div>
        <div class="excerpt"><?php the_excerpt(); ?></div>
        <?php
        the_content();
        echo '<div class="entry-content">';
        echo '</div>';
        echo "</div></a>";
        endwhile;
        ?>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).